# What is the appropriate word for these? -> one day, one month, one year and so on

Tags: grammar, vocabulary, american-english, terminology

I want to know the most appropriate word for these.

- one day
- two days
- three days
- one month
- two months
- three months
- one year
- two years
- three years

The context where these appears is that they are options users of a website can select from a menu to check the data of their weight for the certain range of time.

What's came up in my head is the following.

- period
- date range
- duration

Is there right one in the above list?

Comment: I would use "time period"

Comment: Or maybe "time *span*".